# Configuration graph bipartity

Tags: graph-theory

I am supposed to consider a configuration graph as stated in proof of theorem cited below(source: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1602.05150.pdf).

First things first - do I interpret that right? It's a graph that has possible combinations of n-element sequence as vertices and there is edge between two vertices A, B if it's possible to get sequence corresponding to B with single swap of two elements in A.

My task is to prove that above graph is bipartite. I have tried couple different approaches but they got me nowhere.
The closest one so far (I think) is considering edges as functions:
$ \forall (1\leq i<j\leq N):f_{ij}(T_{1},\ldots,T_{N})=(T_{1},\ldots,T_{i-1},T_{j},T_{i+1},\ldots,T_{j-1},T_{i},T_{j+1},\ldots,T_{N}) $
In this case it comes down to proving that identity is a composition of an even number of functions. However, I cannot seem to be able to write it down formally.

Edit:

> Given a graph $ G=(V,E) $ with $V=\{1,\ldots,n\}$ we place on every vertex a token $T_{1},\ldots,T_{n}$. A swap is an exchange of tokens on adjacent vertices. We consider the algorithmic question of finding a shortest sequence of swaps such that token $T_{i}$ is on vertex i.
>
> [...]
>
> The algorithm is breadth-first search in the configuration graph. The nodes $V$ of the configuration graph $G=(V,E)$ consist of all n! possible configurations of tokens of the vertices of G. Two configurations A and B are adjacent if there is a single swap that transofrms A to B.

Comment: It is generally frowned upon to make us go to other sites and sources. Please retype the problem here, or include an image if it is a cumbersome graphic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can view the $n!$ configurations as the set of permutations on $\{1,\dots, n\}$. It is a well known result in group theory that every permutation can be written as a sequence of transpositions (swapping of two elements). This sequence will be of odd or even length and thus the permutation will be considered an odd or even permutation respectively. It is a known result that if we were to take an odd permutation and write it as a different sequence of transpositions, then that sequence will still be of odd length. Similarly for even permutations. In other words, the evenness or oddness of a permutation is a property of the permutation itself.

Thus, for your graph, youll have one vertex set corresponding to even permutations and another corresponding to odd permutations. Clearly, you can't have an edge between an even permutation to another even permutation, otherwise that means they differ by one transposition and thus it would be possible to write one as a sequence of an odd number of transpositions, a contradiction. Similarly, you can't have edges between the odd permutations. Thus, the graph is bipartite.